# Copy files to a /var/www folder on winscp gives permission denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, winscp

Hi i am trying to give the the folder www the permission to allow the copying but i keep on getting the permission denied error.I know this question it has been asked multiple times I tried all the method but still having no luck. i've tried to follow this post but still don't get the same error now it is worst MY ip on the browser is returning You don't have permission to access / on this server.

here what stat shows

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-251 ~]$ stat /var/www
File: ‘/var/www’
Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: ca01h/51713d    Inode: 264049      Links: 7
Access: (0666/drw-rw-rw-)  Uid: (  500/ec2-user)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2015-03-12 03:50:52.000000000 +0000
Modify: 2015-08-06 08:08:36.296561953 +0000
Change: 2015-08-06 14:46:40.304299109 +0000
Birth: -
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-18-251 ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `x` Access for user to be able to write in directory. Try `chmod u+x /var/www`.

Comment: yep this worked but i still get this message on the "You don't have permission to access / on this server." "Apache/2.2.29 (Amazon) Server at 52.28.184.10 Port 80" on the browser.

Comment: It depends on how do you have your webserver set up. More info you will see in some server log, I guess `/etc/apache/error.log` or similar on other linux distributions.